# after dismissing a viewController, the contentOffset from my tableView was changed to (0, -64)

Tags: uitableview, ios8, contentoffset

The following code is not working.It makes tableview to move from (0,0) content offset to  (0,-64) content offset.

```
-(BOOL)automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets
{
    return NO;
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = NO;
}
```

This issue is in iOS8 only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.navigationcontroller.navigationbar.transculent = NO;
```

**or**

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setTransculent:NO];
```

we have to set either of the above statements to fix the `tableview` scroll issue.In `xib` we have to select navigation bar as infered and set the above appearance statement in `AppDelegate`.